# What would be a recommended choice of SSIS component to perform SFTP or FTPS task?

Tags: ssis, ftp, sftp, ftps

Sometimes normal FTP doesn't quite cut it...  When you need to do secure FTP via SSIS packages, which product would you recommend?

Before answering, please see if someone has already suggested the same thing and, if so, vote it up.

**`NOTE:`** Ideally, it needs to handle both SSH and SSL FTP connections, but I'd consider two separate components if it makes the most sense....

Comment: Buy Taskfactory for $1,450 and ignore everything else in this thread, get 21 other insane features for SSIS, and win. You do not need a component for FTPS in SSIS as that is part of the .NET framework and available inside an FTP task in SSIS. http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Rebex.net File Transfer Pack](http://www.rebex.net/file-transfer-pack/default.aspx) for SFTP and FTP transfers in .NET.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this one.  Hadn't heard of it before, but it looks like they have plenty of code samples and examples.  It's not strictly for SSIS, but that's actually a selling-point for one of the other developers, since it could be used in other apps as well.

Comment: This worked great in the regular IDE. When I tried it in SSIS Script Task, I was unable to add it as a reference?!  Any ideas?

Comment: We ended up going to with Rebex after trying both it and Secure Blackbox. Rebex seemed the best for our needs.

Comment: D Scott: adding it as a reference is described at http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2008/10/03/how-to-register-sftp-and-ftp-ssl-for-use-in-ssis-package.aspx

Comment: I dont think this is free.

Comment: This is not free for sure

Answer (score 4):

Not actually SSIS component. But you may consider checking [guide how to use WinSCP open source SFTP client as task in SSIS](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).

Answer (score 3):

[Secure Blackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbbsrv/ssis-ssh-connection-task.php?referer1=google&referer2=adwords_sbbsrv_sshssis&gclid=CM-SktPNg5YCFRfAQAodbQXjEw) does SSH and is supposed to be good, but no personal experience.

Comment: I'm looking into this as well, but so far I haven't run across anyone who has actually used it.

Answer (score 2):

A coworker pointed out [CozyRoc](http://www.cozyroc.com/), but I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: I used a beta version of the 1.2 library in SQL Server 2005 and it worked well enough.  I didn't like that you had to create the task first before creating the connection to the FTP server, but it worked well after that point.

Answer (score 1):

our [Rebex File Transfer Pack](http://www.rebex.net/file-transfer-pack/default.aspx) includes both SFTP and FTP/SSL.

I wrote a blogpost about registering the component for use in SSIS package:
http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2008/10/03/how-to-register-sftp-and-ftp-ssl-for-use-in-ssis-package.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SSIS Task Factory from Pragmatic Works.... Community Edition is FREE

[SSIS Custom Tasks and Components](http://www.pragmaticworks.com/products/business-intelligence/taskfactory/)

including 
SFTP Task (Secure FTP ... FTPS)
Compression/Zip Task
Upsert Destination (Bulk Update or Insert)

and many more....

They have some really kool components

Comment: SFTP component is NOT free, though.