# Is SFTP possible in SSIS package without using WinSCP

Tags: ssis, sftp

I am having a SSIS package which does FTP. Now i need to change this to do SFTP, is there a possibility i can use FTP Task and do SFTP, or do SFTP without using WinSCP.

Comment: does this help?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491423/why-doesnt-ssis-support-sftp-natively

Comment: Not out of the box. There are other tasks available you can use any SFTP library in script, or use an SFTP powershell command. Paid components are generally better as most of the SFTP tasks you'll find seem a bit ... dated and the UI is a bit clunky

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Method to SFTP or FTPS Files via SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409491/best-method-to-sftp-or-ftps-files-via-ssis) - And many others - What makes you ask yet another question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl because there is no good answer. If you had to use SFTP you probably encountered this problem too

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box. There are other tasks available you can use any SFTP library in script, or use an SFTP powershell command. Paid components are generally better as most of the SFTP tasks you'll find seem a bit ... dated and the UI is a bit clunky.

For starters, you could check  [SSIS SFTP Task Component](https://ssissftp.codeplex.com/releases). It depends on SharpSSH, a library that hasn't been updated since 2013

On the other hand, [Posh-SSH](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH) and the underlying library, [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) had a release only a few weeks ago.

In my case, I ended up using Posh-SSH with a PowerShell script because it allowed me to compare the directory listings of remote and local files, detect the *new* files with standard PowerShell operations and download only the newer/changed files using SFTP.

For example, the following Powershell function will retrieve both listings and compare them using the Compare-Object command:

```
function get-diffs( $session,$remotePath,$localPath)
{
    $remoteFiles=Get-SFTPChildItem -SFTPSession $session -Path $remotePath 
    $localFiles=Get-ChildItem $localPath

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localFiles -DifferenceObject $remoteFiles -Property "Name" -PassThru
}
```

The result contains a `SideIndicator` property that shows which files have to be moved from one side to another. Eg:

```
$newFiles=$diffs|where SideIndicator -eq '=>'
...
foreach ($f in $newFiles)
{
    Get-SFTPFile -SFTPSession $session -RemoteFile $f.FullName -LocalPath $dropFolder -Overwrite
}
```

Doing the same thing with SSIS would be a *lot* harder.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to SFTP server using execute process task in ssis? Lets say we have WinScp also installed